# Y limits for ggplot with sec.axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a dual-y plot using sec.axis, but just can't get both axis to scale properly.

I've been following instructions found in this thread: [ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)

But everytime I change the lower limit in ylim.prim to anything other than 0, it messes up the the entire plot. For visualization reasons, I need very specific y limits for both axes. Also, when I change geom_col to geom_line, it messes up the limits for the secondary axis, too.

```
climate <- tibble(
  Month = 1:12,
  Temp = c(23,23,24,24,24,23,23,23,23,23,23,23),
  Precip = c(101,105,100,101,102, 112, 101, 121, 107, 114, 108, 120)
  )

ylim.prim <- c(0, 125)   # in this example, precipitation
ylim.sec <- c(15, 30)    # in this example, temperature

b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])

ggplot(climate, aes(Month, Precip)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y = a + Temp*b), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Temperature"),) +
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12)
```

[image: GGplot1]

```
ylim.prim <- c(0, 125)   # in this example, precipitation
ylim.sec <- c(15, 30)    # in this example, temperature

b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])

ggplot(climate, aes(Month, Precip)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = a + Temp*b), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Temperature"),) +
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12)
```

[image: GGplot2]

```
ylim.prim <- c(95, 125)   # in this example, precipitation
ylim.sec <- c(15, 30)    # in this example, temperature

b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])

ggplot(climate, aes(Month, Precip)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = a + Temp*b), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Temperature"),) +
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12)
```

[image: GGplot3]

Comment: I think your equation for `a` should be `ylim.prim[1] - b*ylim.sec[1]`.  If I use that instead of your definition the remapping between the two scales seems to work and the limits for the two axes match your definitions.

Answer (score 6):

From what I see in the code, your conversion between the two scales was a little too simple.

In order to get the result that I think your were aiming for, it is necessary to normalize the temperature data (this way you can vary the spread and mean, and make it suit your primary y-scale) and then compute the reverse normalization for the secondary y-axis.

By normalisation I mean: `(Temp - mean(TEMP))/sd(TEMP)`, where `TEMP` is an array of all values, and `Temp`is the specific value to be plotted.

*`EDIT:` Since ggplot2 only allows for transformations of the original scale, and has no option to set unique limits for the secondary axis, there is no easy option to set the `ylim` of the secondary y axis. BUT, there is a way to do it, which is quite hacky, but I will show here.*

By solving the normalisation for both boundaries with a simple linear model (or any other solving method) the transformation of the secondary y axis can be made to match unique limits.
The linear transformation I use introduces the two variables `a` and `s`. `s` is a scaling factor that the result is multiplied by, which allows varying the spread of the plotted data in respect to the primary y-axis. The variable `a` shifts the resulting transformation along the y-axis.

The transformation is:

```
y = a + (Temp - mean(TEMP))/sd(TEMP)) * s
```

The calculation works as follows:

```
climate <- tibble(
  Month = 1:12,
  Temp = c(23,23,24,24,24,23,23,23,23,23,23,23),
  Precip = c(101,105,100,101,102, 112, 101, 121, 107, 114, 108, 120)
  )

ylim.prim <- c(95, 125)   # in this example, precipitation
ylim.sec <- c(15, 30)    # in this example, temperature

TEMP <- climate$Temp #needed for coherent normalisation

# This is quite hacky, but it works if you want to set a boundary for the secondary y-axis
fit = lm(b ~ . + 0, 
   tibble::tribble(
     ~a, ~s,  ~b,
      1,  (ylim.sec[1] - mean(TEMP))/sd(TEMP),  ylim.prim[1],
      1,  (ylim.sec[2] - mean(TEMP))/sd(TEMP), ylim.prim[2]))

a <- fit$coefficients['a']
s <- fit$coefficients['s']
```

To adjust the secondary y-axis scale back to your values, simply do every step in the calculation in reverse.

This way you can have a nice & adjustable overlay of the two time series:

```
ggplot(climate, aes(Month, Precip)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = (a + ((Temp - mean(TEMP))/sd(TEMP)) * s) ), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", 
                     limits=ylim.prim,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a) / s * sd(TEMP) + mean(TEMP), name = "Temperature"),) +
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12) +
  theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(colour = "red"))
```

[image: temperature vs precipitation plot with secondary y axis scaled to fit]

Comment: Where did you applied the ylim.sec in ggplot( ) function ?

Comment: @DarwinPC Good question, thanks for pointing that out! I modified my answer to use the ylim.sec values, which complicates the steps of the transformation a bit, but it does work like this for linear transformations at least. Needless to say, that this is quite hacky and against ggplot2's philosophy...

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
  ggplot(climate, aes(Month, Precip)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_line(aes(y = 4.626*Temp), color = "red") +
    scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./4.626, name = "Temperature"),) +
    scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12)
```

Let me know if you need further explanation. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution showing the direct algebraic transformation. Uses full axis extents for both y-axis variables.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 61),
                  a = c(50:-10),
                  b = c(-100:-40)
                  )

a.diff <- max(dat$a) - min(dat$a)
b.diff <- max(dat$b) - min(dat$b)
a.min <- min(dat$a)
b.min <- min(dat$b)

ggplot(dat, aes(Date, a)) +
    geom_line(color = "blue") +
    geom_line(aes(y = (b - b.min) / b.diff * a.diff + a.min), color = "red") +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~((. -a.min) * b.diff / a.diff) + b.min,
                                           name = "b")) +
    theme(
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```